# How thread safe is this?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my Color class, I have a private static bool which determines if a new Color should premultiply its alpha. Since this value is only ever read (and only set before any secondary threads are created), is it safe to instance 2 colors on 2 threads?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but why not pass it as a  parameter to the thread constructors?

Comment: @unapersson I doubt that I will actually ever need to do the above, but I just wanted to see if it was safe just in case.

Comment: Or as a template parameter. Such a thing seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading memory from multiple threads is thread safe.  Its when you're changing and reading memory at the same time that you run into troubles.